# How to extract rows in numpy structured array that satisfy some condition?

Tags: python, numpy

lets say I create structured array in numpy:

```
name = ['Tom' , 'Jim', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Greg']
height = [188, 160, 160, 157, 180]
pet = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog', 'cat']

a = np.zeros(len(name), dtype=[('name', 'U30'), ('height', 'i'), ('pet', 'U30')])

a['name'] = name
a['height'] = height
a['pet'] = pet
```

Is there a way in numpy to extract those rows which satisfy some condition. For example:

```
'height' == 160 and 'pet' == 'cat'
```

Comment: please next time make sure you put the code there is actually working so that the person who is trying to answer doesn't spend time cleaning it. Like wrapping strings around with ' ' ...

Comment: I edited your question to clean up your code so it's runnable.

Comment: sorry for that , next time I ll check ;]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, Here is a way to do it with `numpy`

```
a[(a['height'] == 160) & (a['pet'] == 'cat')]
```

Which returns:

```
array([('Jim', 160, 'cat')],
      dtype=[('name', '<U30'), ('height', '<i4'), ('pet', '<U30')])
```

If you want to get just the index at which the conditions are satisfied, use `numpy.where`:

```
np.where((a['height'] == 160) & (a['pet'] == 'cat'))
# (array([1]),)
```

**Caveat**:

That being said, `numpy` *might* not be the best tool for your purposes. To see why, consider what your array `a` looks like:

```
>>> a
array([('Tom', 188, 'dog'), ('Jim', 160, 'cat'), ('Alice', 160, 'fish'),
       ('Alice', 157, 'dog'), ('Greg', 180, 'cat')],
      dtype=[('name', '<U30'), ('height', '<i4'), ('pet', '<U30')])
```

It's kind of hard to read...

Think about using `pandas` for organizing tabular data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'height':height, 'pet':pet})
>>> df

   height   name   pet
0     188    Tom   dog
1     160    Jim   cat
2     160  Alice  fish
3     157  Alice   dog
4     180   Greg   cat

>>> df.loc[(df.height==160) & (df['pet'] == 'cat')]
   height name  pet
1     160  Jim  cat
```

Comment: If you really need to see it column-wise... not as fancy, but better than adding a whole package, consider ... a.reshape(a.shape[0], 1) for a quick view